# Malwares affecting browsers through Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, malware

Whenever I sign in to my Google account through Chrome, malwares like wander butst ads get installed in my laptop affecting all the browsers. Is there any problem with my Google Chrome settings or Google account and what are the ways to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your extensions. You could have something stuck in there that is creating ads.

Also, as I'm sure you don't keep giving it permission to install, your machine probably has a malicious program on it. Assuming Windows, open the control panel and go to the "Uninstall a program" section. Remove any programs that you don't trust, or by authors you don't recognize. Google anything you aren't sure about.

To make a very clean sweep, give [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) a shot. It's free and should remove anything you missed.

Last, go back and check your extensions again. If everything is clear there, go to your settings page, open the advanced settings, navigate to the Privacy section, open the content settings menu, go to Plugins, and click the "Manage individual plugins" link. If anything here looks fishy (it probably won't) google it. Otherwise, you should be malware free.

Note that this is a deep clean. You probably only need to clear your extensions and run Malwarebytes to solve most malware problems.

Comment: Thanks for recommending me Malwarebytes.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost I would run CCleaner. It can be downloaded from https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner.  Then I would run malwarebytes.  And in that order.