# Google Chrome extension malware?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow, malware

I'm having some problem with probably some extension in Google Chrome. It randomly on random page inputs into the console following commands and it shows alert windows which redirects to another page. I did malware and virus scans but nothing, so I though that it is done by some extension in Chrome.

[image: Console logs]

First link: `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?&remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@201276/&can_dock=true&dockSide=undocked`

Second link: `http://applestore.cz.com--free.gift/?brand=Samsung&model=Galaxy%20S%20III&voluumdata=vid..00000001-cb01-4240-8000-000000000000__vpid..03fdc800-53ce-11e5-8b25-ad7d9ffb36ba__caid..a08c0ce3-20f9-4dca-87e2-d12e42859ffc__rt..DJ__lid..fb742079-c792-492d-b86f-1555a7513759__oid1..eb40593b-fc82-46de-b925-5ccc4c78f008__var1..309710__rd..onclickads%5C.%5Cnet__aid..__sid..&zoneid=309710`

Have you ever seen something like this before?

I think that that it is done by [Popup blocker pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popup-blocker-pro/kiodaajmphnkcajieajajinghpejdjai) Which I've installed recently because I really hate force popup windows and Chrome in default cannot block them (I've set it in settings its not working properly). I cannot test it because it's really random and like once per day.

So I'd like to ask if it is done by the blocker (currently uninstalled - waiting if it will do the alert or not) do you know how can I block force popups? And if it will not be done by the blocker is there any way how can I find out what does it do or how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Btw hope that there is a place for something like this cause there is really lots of StackExchanges and I didn't know where else to ask. So I hope it will be fine in here.

Comment: remove all extensions and seexif it atill happens. no point on answering if you dont try that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed that is classic malware behavior.  Also [check add-remove programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077615/malwares-affecting-browsers-through-chrome?rq=1) for anything not fully trusted or needed.

Try Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Free and Hitmanpro to check and confirm you are clean.  [Also here is a Really detailed malware removal guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/33evdi/suggested_reading_official_malware_removal_guide/).

uBlock Origin (or uBlock) are the currently popular Blocker recommendations.  Ad-Block and derivatives accepts money to white list companies including Microsoft to allow non-intrusive popups.

Comment: this generic help is not an answer specific to the chrome extension quesion. if you want to comment do so in a comment.

Comment: the question reports the extension was already uninstalled, but your right it may be another extension as well.  The reviews of the extension have some reports of it not working.  Its quite hard to get a smoking gun diagnosis of that add-in.

Comment: i think the o.p. needs to try more things before we can give an answer

Comment: I can confirm, that the extension had malware, after removing no more background scripts were injected. Also thanks for links, some of the anti-malware sw found some tracking cookies. uBlock worked find for me but I didn't find any possibility to block only popups as I don't wanna block normal ads cause I thing normal ad users should have some profit I don't see it offensively :)